# how to upload & save pdf file on server with javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, server, javafx-8

I want to save some pdf in a folder directory that is on a server.And I don't want to use database.I'm using javafx 8.How do I do that?

Comment: In addition to the code using the code in the linked answer, you probably need to move the code doing the actual download to a thread other than the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not clear.I don't want what you referred to. I want to upload & save my pdf file on the server. and also download it when its needed.and How do I do that?

Comment: Thanks.What You referred to answered my one question."How do I download the file?" . But I also need to Upload and save my file on the server.I'm editing my question.